# Leaflet API - select one overlay at a time like base layers

Tags: leaflet

I have a set of basemaps and overlays on my simple web mapping application with Leaflet. I would like to be able to select one overlay at a time like base layers so that multiple selection of overlays is not allowed.

I cannot make those overlays into base layers as at least one base layer should be visible on the map at any time.

Currently I have the following code snippet.

```
var baseLayers = {baselayer1, baselayer2, baselayer3};
var overlayMaps = {overlay1, overlay2, overlay3};
L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a second `L.Control.Layers`, with your "overlays" as "base layers".

```
var baseLayers = {baselayer1, baselayer2, baselayer3};
var overlayMaps = {overlay1, overlay2, overlay3};
L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);
L.control.layers(overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

Keep in mind that "overlay" and "base layer" is just nomenclature for `L.Control.Layers` ("base layer"s are exclusive among themselves in the context of a layers control, "overlay"s are not). Those words have no meaning in the context of a `L.Map`, which means that if you don't have a layers control, then you cannot tell a layer is a base layer or an overlay.

Answer (score 4):

Another option: a grouped layer control.

Working example:
http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/senate/index.html

Where I found the code:
https://github.com/ismyrnow/leaflet-groupedlayercontrol

How I used the code:

```
var groupedOverlays = {
        "Reprensitives":{
            "Senate":senate,
            "Assembly":assembly,
            "US House":congress
        }

    };

    var options = {
      // Make the "Landmarks" group exclusive (use radio inputs)
      exclusiveGroups: ["Reprensitives"],
      // Show a checkbox next to non-exclusive group labels for toggling all
      groupCheckboxes: true
    };

    // Use the custom grouped layer control, not "L.control.layers"
    var layerControl = L.control.groupedLayers(baseMaps, groupedOverlays, options);
    map.addControl(layerControl);
   // End of switcher control.
```